# Implementing visitors statistics for many users

Tags: ajax, database, postgresql, statistics, visitors

I'm facing a challenge and I need your opinion, let me explain:

I have a database of around 300 000 users, which all have a profile page, and I would like to store the amounts of visitors that visit their profile on a weekly ( or daily?) basis for reporting purpose (graph would be available on their admin page).

I'm thinking about doing so in a dedicated table (let's call it "stat") organised as follows:

- id / integer (id of users -- unique)
- current_ip / text (serialized array of ip of visitors of the current period)
- statistics / text (serialized array of statistics per period)

I'm thinking about an AJAX request on the profile page that would filter only non-robot user, check if the ip exist in the ´current_ip´ table (with a LIKE request) and if it doesn't exist I would unserialize the ´current_ip´, push the ip of the new visitor, serialize the ip and UPDATE the table.

At the end of each period (so every week or every day) I'm thinking about a cron task counting the number of ip un the 'current_ip', push that number (with the date) in the 'statistic' value (using the same method than previously explained), and then delete the ´curent_ip´ value so it´s empty for the next period.

Btw I'm using php5 and PostgreSQL (9.1) with an i5 (4 x 3.2 Ghz) in an ubuntu 12.04LTS dedicated server with SSD and 16g RAM.

Is that the best, easiest or fastest way of doing it? Am I all wrong?!  Should I use 1 line per period instead of using a serialized array to store historical values?!

Any suggestion is welcome =)

Cheers

Geoffrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HBase counters instead of postgres. It's much more eficient for that purpose.

Comment: Maybe, but I use postgreSQL for all the other data and I want to make an INNER JOIN on user.id on the admin area =)

Comment: Also HBase is suitable when you have billions of rows with millions of columns, in my case that would be 300 000 rows x 3 columns so we're not there yet ^^

Comment: HBase is suitable in any case when you unable to get response from RDBMS during reasonable time. The number of columns and number of rows aren't parameters. HBase key option in your case is counters that cancel the need to use nightly jobs of RDBS - you know desired statistics exactly every single millisecond without running complex SQL's. As write time to HBase is around ~0.1 millisecond per row you can easily duplicate your data fully or partially into HBase from your RDBMS. Compression will decrease the space requirement ~x10 times.Take a look and you will find completely different world.

Comment: If I have 1000 unique visitors/day and if every visitors visit 5 users, I would have 365 x 1000 x 5 = 2 million rows / year (HBase method) instead of 300 000 rows with 'complex' query (method described in the first post), I think that the first method is faster and easier for reporting purpose dont'u?

Comment: As I see the data model in HBase: you will have "users_stat_daily", "users_stat_weekly" and etc. The key will be user_id + date:"97254610:20130828". For weekly statistics the date will be last date of the week, for monthly last day of the month and etc. During visitor login you add row for all your stat tables. Because in HBase the key is unique the add will be translated into update in case row is already exists. The counter will be updated automatically. Update of 6 stat tables will cost in your case ~ 3 millisecond per log in.

Comment: HBase will compress your data ~ 10 times, PostgreSQL 0, no compression.  Define TTL on tables to clean them automatically. Fast, efficient, no jobs, always updated. In addition you can define users table and keep visitors ip's as version data, 300 k rows.

Comment: That seems smart, but how would you record the visitor's ip? can u please give me an exemple of record? Cause you said "id+date" but what about the ip? Or maybe u considered it as the 'main' row and an insert would be ('ip', 'user_id + date_D', 'user_id + date_W', 'user_id + date_M') ? Should I check if " 'ip' & 'user_id + date_D' " does not exist before insert? Thx =)